# Corona save image to sdcard

Tags: android, image, coronasdk, sd-card

In corona, we use this code to save a image to the internal storage:

```
local baseDir = system.DocumentsDirectory
display.save( groupStage, "drawImage.png",baseDir )
```

but now I want save it to the sdcard. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [link](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/22389-any-way-to-access-the-sdcard/)
Currently, Corona does not provide access to external storage on Android. So, there currently isn't a good solution for you at the moment other than to inform the end-user that they are out of storage space and they need to free up additional space to make room for more of your app's content.

In your particular case, I think the best solution is for us to add Expansion Files support, which allows your app to exceed the 50 MB barrier on Google Play. That's on our to-do list and there is plenty of demand for it. You can find more details about this feature via the link below.

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html